# NodeJS/JS - Sorting based on another array + moving elements efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 arrays:

`var one = ['da22', 'ye66', '17hy']` and

`var two = [{publicID: 'da22', score: '2'}, {publicID: '17hy', score: '2'}, {publicID: 'ye66', score: '2'}]`

I want `two` to be ordered by `publicID` according to `one` so it should be

`two = [{publicID: 'da22', score: '2'}, {publicID: 'ye66', score: '2'}, {publicID: '17hy', score: '2'}]`

Is there a built in method in NodeJS to do this?

I've got it working however its not very efficient. I have a method than can move an element from one index to another `moveFromTo(oldIndex, newIndex` which I'm using with:

```
for (var r=0; r<one.length; r++) {
              if (one[r] != two[r]['publicID']) {
                two.moveFromTo(one.indexOf(two[r]['publicID']), r)
                r=-1; continue;
              }
}
```

But having to use that `r=-1` as things move - although works - doesn't seem like the best of ideas.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Define what you desire to have happen for objects in `two` for which there is no matching `publicID` in `one`.

Comment: @Makyen - there will always be a matching object

Comment: @Makyen - typo fixed

Comment: So there will *always* be an *exact* one-to-one correspondence between `one` and `two`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sort()` and `indexOf()`

```js
var one = ['da22', 'ye66', '17hy'];
var two = [{publicID: 'da22', score: '2'}, {publicID: '17hy', score: '2'}, {publicID: 'ye66', score: '2'}];

var result = two.sort(function(a, b) {
  return one.indexOf(a.publicID) - one.indexOf(b.publicID);
})

console.log(result)
```

You can also create object from `one` and sort by that object.

```js
var one = ['da22', 'ye66', '17hy'];
var two = [{publicID: 'da22', score: '2'}, {publicID: '17hy', score: '2'}, {publicID: 'ye66', score: '2'}];

var o = one.reduce((r, e, i) => {return r[e]=i, r}, {});

var result = two.sort(function(a, b) {
  return o[a.publicID] - o[b.publicID];
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Assigning to `result` is not needed.  [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the array *in place*. In addition, it returns the array. However, assigning it to `result` is equivalent to `two.sort(function ...); var result=two;`.

Comment: Side note.. If you're looking for speed, Array.sort() is not your best option by a considerable margin. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732480/native-javascript-sort-performing-slower-than-implemented-mergesort-and-quicksor

Comment: @PatrickMotard -  The maximum number of items in the array would be 100 - I'm assuming that would be fine?

Comment: If the set is that small then there's likely no reason to over complicate for the sake of performance. Best to choose whatever is most readable no?

Comment: Agreed - @Nenad - that first option works a treat! Thanks

Comment: @NenadVracar  - quick question how does that `a` and `b` parameters correlate in the sort function? i.e. whats it'd doing exactly?

Comment: You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a simpler solution. You need to synchronize the order of elements in two arrays by different properties of elements of these arrays, while the first (target) array preserves its order.

To do that, you can reduce the `two`, and for every current element the reduce function is applied to, put corresponding element of `two` at certain position in resulting array (aka `total`):

```
const one = ['da22', 'ye66', '17hy'];
const two = [{
  publicID: 'da22',
  score: '2'
}, {
  publicID: 'ye66',
  score: '2'
}, {
  publicID: '17hy',
  score: '2'
}];

const sortedTwo = two.reduce((total, current) => {
  total[one.indexOf(current.publicID)] = current; // <- some crazy stuff here

  return total;
}, []);
```

Make sure `publicID` property values in `two` and the values of `one` are perfectly identical sets.

Speed and immutability of the original array included.